# tinyMCE mcimagemanager - upload other files

Tags: tinymce, mcimagemanager

I'm using TinyMCE with ImageManager. I have everything set up right, but i added 'doc,docx,mp3,pdf' to the list of permitted uploadable files in imagemanager's config.php.
In my XAMPP localhost instalation, everything works fine, but when i try to upload anything other than an image or a pdf i get this:

[image]

please, some help? Thanks

Comment: +1 for clear question and image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i just came to the conclusion that my problem wasn't with the extention but with file size.
Sorry for any inconvenience.